# How to become Hybrid airship Pilot?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, lighter-than-air

Are Hybrid Airship pilot different from other aircraft or helicopter pilot?

Comment: By "hybrid airship" do you mean something like the V-22 or are you talking about some kind of lighter-than-air ship?

Comment: [Hybrid airship on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_airship), e.g. [Hybrid Airship from Lockheed Martin](https://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/products/HybridAirship.html).

Comment: Like Lockheed Martins' Blimp (https://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/products/HybridAirship.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are different.  A hybrid airship has the characteristics of an airship, but it also generates lift based on its aerodynamic shape (like a powered aircraft wing).

The FAA defines an airship as having both "Lighter than Air" and "powered aircraft" characteristics.  A hybrid airship falls under the characteristics of an airship, in this sense.  However, as with any aircraft, a specific type rating may be required for a hybrid airship.

Therefore, the path to certification as a pilot of a hybrid airship will likely be very similar to, but distinct from, a typical pilot.  In particular, it may be added on as a rating to an existing pilot certificate.

https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-18.pdf

Comment: @FlightTestFact is right, obtaining a pilot's license for a hybrid airship would require similar but different training. It would be much like earning a pilot's license and adding a type rating for a particular aircraft. The only trouble is that the FAA defines airships as "near-equilibrium". The buoyancy ratio for a hybrid airship may be lower than "near-equilibrium", but the FAA doesn't offer much guidance for any applicable type certificates for these cases (yet).